# How to merge raster quadrangle tiles in qgis?

Tags: qgis, dem, merge

I've downloaded some dem tiles from here http://www.granit.unh.edu/data/search?dset=dem/dem174, which I'd like to merge into a single smooth digital elevation model usinq QGIS.

So far I've tried to use the raster merge function (gdal_merge.py) with default options.  The merge is successful, but null value bands are introduced between the original dem extents that are actually larger than I would have expected from viewing the tiles separately.

How do I get rid of these gaps?

Comment: You can try building a virtual raster. Go to Raster/miscellaneous/build virtual raster (catalog)

Comment: Virtual raster is better, but there are still a few 1-2 cell gaps here and there...